# jQuery v 1.4.2 and 1.6.2 ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/protocosmos/Mh275/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/protocosmos/HyLmS/6/
- The first one works using jQuery 1,4,2
- The latter doesn't, is there something wrong with my code or is it just jQuery's?

EDIT:
updated fiddles, added 1.4.2 version on first, thanks

Comment: There is something wrong with your question

Comment: -1 and voted to close. The URL's are completely different between your statements. If you want to determine if something is broken in the framework, how about you use exactly the same code and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1.4.2 version this is your URL: /ajax_html_echo/

You don't have this in the 1.6.2 version and it's trying to access a file that doesn't exist, so nothing happens.

Updated 1.6.2: http://jsfiddle.net/HyLmS/2/

Comment: oh sorry, I can't seem to get the right jquery version,

Comment: It's not that it can't find a file that doesn't exist. The second URL is not on the same domain and thus the cross domain security settings are blocking the connection.